# android how to get file names from package

Tags: android, file, package

This is Android question.
Does anyone know how I can get file names (as String) from the package and not from the resource folder?
For example, if normal.xml is stored in `src/com.example.xml/normal.xml`, how can i get the name of the file as String?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the .apk (either before installation, or because it is your application, or because it is installed on the device without copy protection and you know its exact path name) you can read it as a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You can place something like this in the OnCreate() method of whatever Activity is loaded in that same namespace:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Other logic...
    AssetManager mgr = getAssets();
    String[] list = mgr.list("./");
    for(String s : list){
        Log.v("Found file:", s);
    }
    //Other logic...
}
```

This will list all of the files found in the same folder that you have your Activity. You can change `"./"` to be whatever relative path you would wish from the `com.example.xml` directory where this Activity lives.